# What is the very last step that Juragedo can be special summoned and tributed

Tags: yu-gi-oh

My opponent declares and attack with a Nekroz holding Nekroz of Decisive Armor in hand. Can I wait until the damage step to special summon and then tribute Juragedo?

**Juragedo**

> During either player's Battle Step: You can Special Summon this card
>   from your hand, and if you do, gain 1000 LP. You can only use this
>   effect of "Juragedo" once per turn. During either player's turn: You
>   can Tribute this card, then target 1 face-up monster you control; it
>   gains 1000 ATK until the end of the next turn.

**Nekroz of Decisive Armor**

> During either player's turn: You can discard this card, then target 1
>   "Nekroz" monster you control; it gains 1000 ATK and DEF until the end
>   of this turn.

To make this as valuable a resource as possible please try and provide detailed reasoning behind your answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Damage step means leaving the battle step, so you could not special summon juragedo in the damage step. You can special summon him during battle step and then tribute during damage step.